# Arrays to filter, copy and past - quick macro method

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I want to make an Excel workbook that I have much quicker.

I have a big product database with the product names, quantities, delivery number and delivery date ([ProductDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEdsY.png)). I put in another sheet the products that I have sold (product names and quantity sold) and want to filter and copy those that are corresponding from the database so I can calculate in the second step the remaining quantity and past the remaining quantity to the database.

Everything is working well and the calculation is good. The only thing is, the `Advancedfilter` `xlfiltercopy` option is too slow if I have to input 5000 lines of product names.

I have heard that arrays are much faster. How could I do that? The current way I do it is like this:

```
Sub UseFilter()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheet1.Range("G1:Z100000").Cells.Delete

Dim lastrow As Long, c As Range
Dim myrange As Range
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim wksSheet As Worksheet
Dim wksSheetDB As Worksheet

lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Sheet1.Columns("G").NumberFormat = "0"
```

Filter product codes from the database according to sold product codes:

```
Set myrange = Range("A1:A" & lastrow)

For Each c In myrange
    If Len(c.Value) <> 0 Then
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Columns("A:D").AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, _
            Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & lastrow), Sheet1.Range("G1"), False
    End If
Next
```

Sort the filtered list first by product code, then by the delivery number:

```
Dim lngRowMax As Long
Dim wsf As WorksheetFunction

With Sheet1

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

Range("G1:J" & lastrow).Sort Key1:=Range("G1:G" & lastrow), _
Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("I1:I" & lastrow), _
Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, DataOption1:=xlSortTextAsNumbers


Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction
lngRowMax = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

End With
```

I'm only interested in filtering and copying of the corresponding product information (`name (A)`, `quantity (B)`, `delivery nr (C)` and `date (D)`). Does anyone know how I can do that?

Thank you very much in advance. I'm really looking forward for a solution that improves the pace of the file. Currently it is unbelievably slow.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem with advanced filter being so slow.  you might want to consider using dictionary.  for my 2 spreadsheets i wanted to compare i made 2 dictionaries and compared the values and it was so amazingly fast.  dictionaries are really easy and a simple google search you can find a ton of tutorials and examples.  good luck.

Comment: Hi @Ashton Morgan
That sounds good. I have seen some videos about dictionaries now but I didn't find the option of filtering and adding the filtered values to the dictionary which I then can paste or show on another sheet. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3598756 do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible solution with dictionaries, but I have only one small issue. I will explain after the code:

```
'Count num rows in the database
NumRowsDB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

' --------------------- SAVE DATABASE DATA -----------------------

'Dictionary for all DB data
Set dbDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dbRange = Range("A2:A" & (NumRowsDB + 1))

For Each SKU In dbRange
If Len(SKU.Value) <> 0 Then

    ' check if the SKU allready exists, if not create a new array list for that dictionary entry
    ' a list is necessary because there can be multiple entries in the db range with the same SKU
    If Not dbDict.Exists(CStr(SKU.Value)) Then
        Set prodList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        dbDict.Add CStr(SKU.Value), prodList
    End If

    ' for this specific product code, save the range where the product information is saved in the dictionary
    rangeStr = "A" & SKU.Row & ":D" & SKU.Row
    dbDict(CStr(SKU.Value)).Add (rangeStr)

End If
Next

' ----------- READ SALE/Reverse/Consumption INFO ------------------

NumRowsSale = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Set saleRange = Range("A2:A" & (NumRowsSale + 1))

Dim unionRange As Range

For Each sale In saleRange
' check if the SKU for the sale exists in db
If Len(sale.Value) <> 0 And dbDict.Exists(CStr(sale.Value)) Then
    For Each dbRange In dbDict(CStr(sale.Value))
        If unionRange Is Nothing Then
            Set unionRange = Range(dbRange)
        Else
            Set unionRange = Union(unionRange, Range(dbRange))
        End If
    Next
End If
Next

unionRange.Copy Destination:=Range("G2") 'copy all received ranges to G2

Set dbDict = Nothing
```

The line **"NumRowsDB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count"** is not working. I have to refer to another sheet (the last sheet which is the current database) to get the data. What is the problem that I cannot refer to another sheet in the same workbook?

Thank you for your suggestions.